# Am trying to increase the amount of items in my cart but this codes is not working for me. Any solution?

Tags: reactjs

```
case 'INCREASE': 
            let tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem)=>{
                if(cartItem.id === action.payload){
                  return{...cartItem, amount: cartItem.amount + 1}
                }
                 return cartItem;  
            })
            return{
                ...state,
                 card:tempCart
            }
```

Am trying to increase the number of items in the cart in React using useReduce hook but the codes is not working and there is no error to.

```
case 'INCREASE': 
            let tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem)=>{
                if(cartItem.id === action.payload){
                  return{...cartItem, amount: cartItem.amount + 1}
                }
                 return cartItem;  
            })
            return{
                ...state,
                 card:tempCart
            }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm gonna assume that your state has `cart`, but not `card` ? In both of your state returns, where you are merging old state with new state, you are using `card`.

Comment: It has been rectified as such. thank you very much.